# Column core_event.hometask does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-postgresql

When I run my Django project on production server, I have this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/core/event/

column core_event.hometask does not exist
LINE 1: ..._event"."is_approved", "core_event"."event_type", "core_even...
```

What I should do to fix it? Now I haven't "hometask" field in my model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_finish = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="event_images/", default='event_images/default.png', blank=True, null=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(null=True)

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('Event', "Мероприятие"),
        ('Lesson', "Урок"),
    )
    event_type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=200, default="Мероприятие")
    topics = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True, null=True)
    materials = ArrayField(models.URLField(), blank=True, null=True)
    possible_users = models.ManyToManyField("core.User", blank=True, related_name='possible_users')
    actual_users = models.ManyToManyField("core.User", blank=True, related_name='actual_users')
    classes = models.ManyToManyField("core.Class", blank=True, related_name='classes')
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, looks like the field existed in the model before but not anymore. However, your `admin.py` still has reference to the old field of `hometask`.

So, go to `admin.py`, search for `hometask`, and remove it.